# Fatal Error While Working On Files

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

I am working on files handling in C++ and I am getting a strange error that I can not remove.I am very new to file handling so please help me out.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
 using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
fstream index;
index.open("file1",ios::app);
index<<"this is the indexed file"<<endl;
index<<"file name /t"<<"size /t"<<"path"<<endl;
//index.close();

string line;
string wordtofind;
char filename[50];
int cnt;

//ifstream index("file1.txt");
if(index.is_open())
{
while(!index.eof())
{
getline(index,line);
cout<<line<<endl;
cout<<"enter a word to be searched"<<endl;
cin>>wordtofind;
cout<<"enter the file in which you want to search the given word"<<endl;
cin>>filename;
//cnt=count(filename,wordtofind);

    int counter=0;
    ifstream file;
    string word;

    file.open(filename);
    if(!file) //If not exist
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;

    }    
    else
    {
        while(file >> word)
        {   
            if(word.compare(wordtofind) == 0)
            counter++;
        }
    }
    file.close(); //always pays to be tidy



cout<<"the number of times the word occured in the file is "<<cnt<<endl;

index.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

> fatal error C1075: end of file found
>   before the left brace '{'

Thank-you!

Comment: you can`t read and write file with one instance of `fstream`. here: `fstream index; index<<"this is the indexed file"<<endl; getline(index,line);` simply close `index` and reopen file '"file1"' with read flag, when you want to read from it

Answer (score 3):

This usually means braces aren't closed. In your case, the while loop isn't closed with the curly braces. I also think you didn't close the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You missed two closing braces. I think your code should end with the lines:

```
            cout<<"the number of times the word occured in the file is "<<cnt<<endl;
        }
        index.close();
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You lose one '}' after cout<<"the number of times the word occured in the file is "<

just like this

}
 index.close();